Merging two tables using beautiful soup to extract links
I would like to scrape the first two tables from the following website:
https://fbref.com/en/comps/22/Major-League-Soccer-Stats
The tables I need are the first two, titled "Eastern Conference" and "Western Conference".
I need to extract the squad links, which I can do successfully for the first table with the following code:
standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/22/Major-League-Soccer-Stats"
data = requests.get(standings_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
standings_table = soup.select_one("table.stats_table")
links = [l.get("href") for l in standings_table.find_all("a")]
links = [l for l in links if "/squads/" in l]
team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]
print(team_urls)

I can't figure out how to also scrape the second table to extract all links in one go for further manipulation.

Try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/22/Major-League-Soccer-Stats"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

table1 = soup.select_one('table[id*="Eastern-Conference_overall"]')
table2 = soup.select_one('table[id*="Western-Conference_overall"]')

for t in [table1, table2]:
    for a in t.select('a[href*="/squads/"]'):
        print(a.text, a["href"], t.caption.text, sep="\t")

Prints:
Inter Miami     /en/squads/cb8b86a2/Inter-Miami-Stats   Eastern Conference Table
FC Cincinnati   /en/squads/e9ea41b2/FC-Cincinnati-Stats Eastern Conference Table
NYCFC   /en/squads/64e81410/New-York-City-FC-Stats      Eastern Conference Table
NY Red Bulls    /en/squads/69a0fb10/New-York-Red-Bulls-Stats    Eastern Conference Table
Toronto FC      /en/squads/130f43fa/Toronto-FC-Stats    Eastern Conference Table
Charlotte       /en/squads/eb57545a/Charlotte-FC-Stats  Eastern Conference Table
Crew    /en/squads/529ba333/Columbus-Crew-Stats Eastern Conference Table
Philadelphia    /en/squads/46024eeb/Philadelphia-Union-Stats    Eastern Conference Table
D.C. United     /en/squads/44117292/DC-United-Stats     Eastern Conference Table
Orlando City    /en/squads/46ef01d0/Orlando-City-Stats  Eastern Conference Table
Nashville       /en/squads/35f1b818/Nashville-SC-Stats  Eastern Conference Table
Atlanta Utd     /en/squads/1ebc1a5b/Atlanta-United-Stats        Eastern Conference Table
CF Montréal     /en/squads/fc22273c/CF-Montreal-Stats   Eastern Conference Table
Fire    /en/squads/f9940243/Chicago-Fire-Stats  Eastern Conference Table
NE Revolution   /en/squads/3c079def/New-England-Revolution-Stats        Eastern Conference Table
RSL     /en/squads/f7d86a43/Real-Salt-Lake-Stats        Western Conference Table
Minnesota Utd   /en/squads/99ea75a6/Minnesota-United-Stats      Western Conference Table
Austin  /en/squads/b918956d/Austin-FC-Stats     Western Conference Table
LA Galaxy       /en/squads/d8b46897/LA-Galaxy-Stats     Western Conference Table
LAFC    /en/squads/81d817a3/Los-Angeles-FC-Stats        Western Conference Table
Rapids  /en/squads/415b4465/Colorado-Rapids-Stats       Western Conference Table
Vancouver W'caps        /en/squads/ab41cb90/Vancouver-Whitecaps-FC-Stats        Western Conference Table
Dynamo FC       /en/squads/0d885416/Houston-Dynamo-Stats        Western Conference Table
St. Louis       /en/squads/bd97ac1f/St-Louis-City-Stats Western Conference Table
Seattle /en/squads/6218ebd4/Seattle-Sounders-FC-Stats   Western Conference Table
Portland Timbers        /en/squads/d076914e/Portland-Timbers-Stats      Western Conference Table
FC Dallas       /en/squads/15cf8f40/FC-Dallas-Stats     Western Conference Table
Sporting KC     /en/squads/4acb0537/Sporting-Kansas-City-Stats  Western Conference Table
SJ Earthquakes  /en/squads/ca460650/San-Jose-Earthquakes-Stats  Western Conference Table


Does it for t in soup.select('table[id*="-Conference_overall"]') not include both tables concisely?

@SIM probably yes, but I think better be explicit with answers to beginners.

It was just an idea, though I knew you were aware of that. Thanks.
